# Getting location error with a Minecraft Education Edition project I'm making

Tags: minecraft, makecode

When I try to run [this code](https://makecode.com/_RbRYeYLohKWc), I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFUht.png), what I'm trying to do is recreate the N'Kuhana's Opinion from RoR2, by healing the player, followed by withering enemies around the player, and I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: Please post your code and error as text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it! I found that using [this code](https://makecode.com/_3t4MemcgkiP1) fixed it!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).